# Let $S,T$ be linear mappings from $V \rightarrow V$ If $ST - I$ is injective then $TS - I$ is injective.

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is to show that $S,T$ be linear mappings from $V \rightarrow V$.
then if $ST - I$ is injective then $TS - I$ is injective. There is a hint given which says that 
$S(TS - I ) = (ST - I)(S)$ which I am okay with.

Here is what I have so far.

Let $(TS-I)(x) = (TS-I)(y)$ for some $x,y \in V$.

Then Applying S to both side gives

$S(TS-I)(x) = (ST-I)(S)(x) = (ST-I)(S)(y)$ thus $S(x) = S(y)$ by injectivity of $ST - I$. 
Now how can I show that x = y or am I going down the wrong path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done. $S(x)=S(y)$ implies $TS(x)=TS(y)$, and you have $(TS-I)(x)=(TS-I)(y).$

Comment: @ See-Woo Lee Not sure what you mean by your last ... statement.

Comment: @JamesDickens I edited.

Comment: to show injectivity you have to show that x = y. I started with $(TS-I)(x) = (TS-I)(y)$

Comment: @JamesDickens Yes, so we have $TS(x)=TS(y)$ and $(TS-I)(x)=(TS-I)(y)$, which implies $x=I(x)=I(y)=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $(TS-I)(x)=0$, this implies that $TS(x)=x, STS(x)=S(x), (ST-I)(S(x))=0$, since $ST-I$ is injective, $S(x)=0$. We deduce that $(TS-I)(x)=TS(x)-x=0=-x$. Thus $x=0$ and $TS-I$ is injective.

Comment: This is correct thank you/